# Is there a way to make margin on the IMG tag clickable to close a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, margin

I am using the W3 school tutorial to help me with some ui components in this project.

Right now the margin on the image modal is preventing the user from clicking on the sides of the image to exit the modal. Aside from clicking the X to close the modal, I also want to give the user the option to close the modal by clicking on the "white" space of the modal around the image. The margin on my image is preventing that area from being clickable to close the modal.

What can I change in my css or html do to allow the margin to be clickable to close the modal?

Code: https://codepen.io/jkramer25/project/editor/AooxzJ

Live demo: https://000582278.codepen.website/

```html
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " js";</script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
      <title>Horizontal Timeline</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <section class="cd-h-timeline js-cd-h-timeline margin-bottom-md">
    
        <div class="cd-h-timeline__container container">
          <div class="cd-h-timeline__dates">
            <div class="cd-h-timeline__line">
              <ol>
                <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/1839" class="cd-h-timeline__date cd-h-timeline__date--selected">1839</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1841" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1841</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1902" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1902</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1904" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1904</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1912" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1912</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1918" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1918</a></li>
              </ol>
    
              <span class="cd-h-timeline__filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__line -->
          </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__dates -->
            
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#0" class="text-replace cd-h-timeline__navigation cd-h-timeline__navigation--prev cd-h-timeline__navigation--inactive">Prev</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0" class="text-replace cd-h-timeline__navigation cd-h-timeline__navigation--next">Next</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__container -->
     
        <div class="timeline-indicators-flex container"><!--Previous, Next, Swipe tip-->
          <div class="timeline-indication color-contrast-medium align-left">
            <p>Previous</p>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-indication color-contrast-medium align-center">
            <p id="swipe-tip">Use arrows and select year for history details</p>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-indication color-contrast-medium align-right">
            <p>Next</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="cd-h-timeline__events">
          <ol>
    <!-- ------------------------SLIDE 1-1839----------------------- -->
            <li class="cd-h-timeline__event cd-h-timeline__event--selected text-component">
              <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container"> 
    <!--
                <div class="jumplinks-timeline">
                  <a href="#hammacher-history">
                    <div class="jumplinks-timeline-button">Hammacher History</div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#us-history">
                    <div class="jumplinks-timeline-button">US History</div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              -->          
                <div id="#hammacher-history"></div>
                <div class=timeline-image-flex>
                  <div>
                    <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1839</h2>
                    <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
                  </div>
                  <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
                    <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click images to enlarge</p>
                    <img class="myImg" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History-100x100_1.jpg" data-large-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History.jpg" alt="Albert Hammacher">
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium"> 
                    Albert Hammacher, the man who would eventually provide half of our company's name, is born on February 16, 1839 in Leichlingen, a town in the North Rhine-Westphalia region of Germany. Hammacher would come to be viewed as one of the leading figures in the hardware industry in the U.S. and Germany during the late 19th and early 20th centuries.
                  </p>    
    
    <hr class="timeline-divider">
    
                <div id="us-history"></div>
                <div class=timeline-image-flex>
                  <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
                  <img class="myImg"
                    src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_US_History-100x100.jpg" style="width: 100%;max-width: 100px;" data-large-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_US_History.jpg" alt="George Armstrong Custer">
                </div>
                <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
                  United States Army officer George Armstrong Custer is born in Ohio. Custer developed a strong reputation leading Union
                  troops during the Civil War-despite graduating last in his class at West Point-and attained the rank of brigadier
                  general at age 23. After the Civil War, he was dispatched to the west to fight in the Indian Wars. Custer and all the
                  men with him (two of his brothers among them) were killed at the Battle of the Little Bighorn in 1876, in a battle that
                  has come to be known as "Custer's Last Stand."
                </p> 
              </div>                      
            </li>
    <!-- ------------------------SLIDE 2-1841----------------------- -->
            <li class="cd-h-timeline__event text-component">
              <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container">
                <div id="#hammacher-history"></div>
                <div class=timeline-image-flex>
                  <div>
                    <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1841</h2>
                    <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
                  </div>
                  <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
                    <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
                  <img class="myImg"
                    src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1841_HS_History-100x100.jpg" data-large-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1841_HS_History.jpg" alt="William Schlemmer">
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
                  William Schlemmer, whose name will come to be associated with a landmark New York City store and America's
                  longest-running catalog, is born on April 20, 1841 in the Westphalia region of Germany.
                </p>
    
    <hr class="timeline-divider">
    
                <div id="us-history"></div>
                <div class=timeline-image-flex>
                  <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
                  <img class="myImg"
                    src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1841_US_History-100x100.jpg" data-large-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1841_US_History.jpg" alt="William Henry Harrison">
                </div>
                <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
                  William Henry Harrison served the shortest tenure of any U.S. president, just 32 days, and became the first to die in
                  office. Vice President John Tyler is sworn in as the nation's 10th president on April 4, 1841.
                </p>
              </div>
            </li>       
          </ol>
        </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__events -->
      </section>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- The Close Button -->
      <div>
        <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times; 
          <div class="tooltiptext">
            <p>Close</p>
          </div>
        </span>
        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>
    </div>   
    <!--Top button-->
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script> <!-- util functions included in the CodyHouse framework -->
    <script src="assets/js/swipe-content.js"></script> <!-- A Vanilla JavaScript plugin to detect touch interactions -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="assets/js/timeline-scrollToTopBtn.js"></script>-->
    <!--Top button script-->
    <script>
      //Get the button
      var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");    
      // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
      window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };   
      function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
          mybutton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          mybutton.style.display = "none";
        }
      }   
      // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
      function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
      }
    </script>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
       // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = $('.myImg');
        var modalImg = $("#img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        $('.myImg').click(function () {
          modal.style.display = "block";
          var newSrc = this.dataset.largeSrc;
          modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
          captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        });
      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      
        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
          span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "none";
          }
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
          window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }
          }
    </script>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```css
     /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
    .myImg {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: zoom-in;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .myImg:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }
    
    /* Modal Content (Image) */
    .modal-content {
        margin: 16px auto;
        display: block;
    }
    
    /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
    #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
    .modal-content, #caption {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
        to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    }
    
    @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform:scale(0)}
        to {transform:scale(1)}
    }
    
    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 15px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus{
        color: #bbb;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tooltiptext{
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -16px !important;
    }
    /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .modal-content {
            width: 75%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want the image to be zoomed by users then just add event listener directly to the image.

Comment: Can't reproduce this: "_preventing the user from clicking on the sides of the image to exit the modal._" - click anywhere and modal closes for me.

Comment: My comment above is wrong, but leaving for others to discover - The margin does block the propagation of the click. The margin in question is only ing the horizontal direction. The codepen output window was tricking me into believing otherwise.

Comment: Why do you have two handlers on the close button? Use of in-line event handlers is discouraged (by everyone other than W3 Schools tutorials apparently [uhg!])

Comment: - The easiest approach would be to create a handler on the entire document when the modal is alive and upon close, remove the close handler from the body.

Comment: That is my JS ignorance showing. It turns out I had a handler for the entire document, my img was wrapped in a div which was causing the unwanted behavior. Thanks!